# Global Counter in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-emr

So, I have a task where job1 creates say file`1`, then job2 creates file`2`, then job1 creates file`3`. Right now, I have a variable i, which I increment in main, every time a job finishes. This works on my local machine, but when I run it on Amazon EMR, it doesn't. I believe that global counters can't be incremented in the main method? Is there a way I can solve this problem.

Comment: Please, may you post your code and be more specific about what your `i` variable represents?

Comment: Its file 'i'. I just need a global counter to do the work of i, but I think we can't increment the value of the global counter in main.